# Elliptical Curve Cryptography in Hadoop

Tags: security, authentication, kerberos, hadoop

Does Hadoop distributed file system use Elliptical curve cryptography anywhere for securing its data? If not, which method is used by it to secure data access?

Comment: What research have you done yourself? This sounds like a typical homework question.

Answer (score 0):

In Hadoop Security (2015) by Ben Spivey & Joey Echeverria, 'at the core of the Hadoop ecosystem is HDFS, which is the filesystem for many other components. Until recently, encrypting data in HDFS was not tatively supported' and that solutions may be quite vendor specific.

So older Hadoop systems may have specific solutions that are not nativly connected to it being 'Hadoop'.

More recent may use HDFS built in encryption. Hadoop file system uses special encryption 'zones' and keys (EZKs and DEKs) that is handled on a designated secure keyserver.

While it seems the standard to configure AES for encryption, there might be vendor specific solutions. And AES is a symmetric algorithm. While Elliptical curve cryptography is a type of asymmetric encryption.

So, No. Unless there is a specific external solution. That isn't 'Hadoop'?

Here is an article that describes how Hadoop could use Elliptic curve-based tokens.

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11416-014-0236-5